# Running 2 projects on apache server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, mamp

I have 2 projects in my htdocs folder: project1 and project2. I am running my project1 on MAMP server. It's located on localhost:8888 (default location provided by MAMP). I want to run my second project2. What changes do I need to do to make it happen?

I added httpd.conf file like this, but it's not working. Is there any elegant way to do this?

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zf2-tutorial-1/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zf2-tutorial-1/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8888/secondproject>
ServerName zf2-tutorial2.localhost
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zf2-tutorial-2/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zf2-tutorial-2/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: define not working ?  This might be better at superuser / serverfault.  Assuming you have a NameVirtualHost config line in your httpd.conf  and both zf2-tutorial.localhost and teamleads.localhost resolve to 127.0.0.1 it *should* work.  but what is the exact error / issue you are seeing.

Comment: second project is not running. Ok.. I am getting this. Where do I need to setup 127.0.0.1 as in server name?

Comment: your browser needs to send the host header, so you need to access it via http://teamleads.localhost:8080/  it appears that you are on a Mac,  so you would need to add teamleads.localhost to your /etc/hosts file

Answer (score 1):

Seems good, except that `<VirtualHost *:8888/secondproject>` is supposed to be just `<VirtualHost *:8888>`. Also, don't forget to add lines binding `zf2-tutorial.localhost` and `zf2-tutorial2.localhost` to `127.0.0.1` to your `/etc/hosts` file and restart Apache.

Comment: I did it, as you have described. But, I am accessing project 1 only even if I change my URL for second project. I got same result for zf1.tutorial1.localhost:8888 and zf2-tutorial2.localhost:8888

Comment: Make sure the [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive is uncommented, in your case it should be `NameVirtualHost *:8888`.

Comment: I have 2 virtual hosts in httpd.conf file. When I uncomment 1 of these then it runs fine. But still if I change URL names then I am getting the same directory access.. In this case if I need to access 1 of these project, then I have to uncomment 1 virtualhost every time.

Comment: [Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) you can find an example of virtual host configuration. Just change 80 to 8888 if you want Apache to listen on a non-standard port.